# reprepro and gpg-agent - passphrase won't be cached

Tags: debian, repository, gpg, gpg-agent

I'm getting a little frustrated here, maybe you got an idea what the problem could be:

- I have a buildprocess with a few reprepro commands at the end
- The buildscript is executed with sudo

  ```
  ( cd "$PUBLISHDIR" && \
  reprepro -Vb . -C untested remove squeeze foobar && \
  reprepro -Vb . -C untested includedeb squeeze ./foobar_*.deb && \
  reprepro -Vb . -C untested list squeeze foobar )
  ```
- I have gpg set up and the key is added. the agent is running

  ```
  ps lax | grep gpg-agent

  1  1002 25345     1  20   0  19284   996 -      Ss   ?          0:00 /usr/bin/gpg-agent --daemon --sh
  ```
- My gpg-agent.conf is set up too

  ```
  # ignore-cache-for-signing
  enable-ssh-support
  write-env-file /home/daily/.gnupg/gpg-agent-info
  default-cache-ttl 31536000
  default-cache-ttl-ssh 31536000
  max-cache-ttl 31536000
  max-cache-ttl-ssh 31536000
  debug-all
  ```
- And i start the agent like this in the .bashrc

  ```
  GNUPGHOME=~/.gnupg
  GPGAGENT=/usr/bin/gpg-agent
  PID_FILE=$GNUPGHOME/gpg-agent-info

  if grep -qs '^[[:space:]]*use-agent' "$GNUPGHOME/gpg.conf" "$GNUPGHOME/options" && test -x $GPGAGENT & then
    if [ -r "$PID_FILE" ]; then
      . "$PID_FILE"
      count=`ps lax | grep "/usr/bin/gpg-agent" | grep "$SSH_AGENT_PID" | wc -l`
      if [ $count -eq 0 ]; then
        if ! $GPGAGENT 2>/dev/null; then
          $GPGAGENT --daemon --sh > "$PID_FILE"
          . "$PID_FILE"
          echo "INFO::agent started"
        fi
      else
        echo "INFO::agent already running"
      fi
    fi
  fi
  ssh-add
  ```

But no matter how often I run the whole process, it will always ask me for the passphrase during the sign-process of reprepro.
I thought the agent would cache this passphrase and next execution it will be stored and not beeing asked anymore... but it does ask for the passphrase... again and again...

can anyone think of a mistake or something else maybe why it always asks for the passphrase?

Comment: You are running the gpg-agent as a different user than the build script.  Are you sure you have `sudo` preserving the environment as necessary?

Comment: well, don't really know if that matters. I just put a sudo in front of the calls of the agent in the .bashrc. It asked me for my sudo passwords of course when i logged in and started the agent with id 29338. echo $GPG_AGENT_INFO said "/tmp/gpg-aitI9v/S.gpg-agent:29338:1" means i started the agent as sudo and started the reprepro as sudo. still asking for the passphrase during signing process... thanks for any more help or ideas...!

Comment: Where did you run `echo $GPG_AGENT_INFO` from?  Try putting it in your build script and see what it says.

Comment: @depquid Make that an answer so that this question can be marked answered.

Comment: @HaukeLaging Is it answered?  I know what the problem is, but I don't know that the solution has been determined yet.  If properly configured, `sudo -E` might work, but I'm not sure it's secure.

Comment: well you asked the right question by asking for "echo $GPG_AGENT_INFO". I ran into too many problems with that multiusersolution, so i changed everything to one user - problem solved... thank you very much @depquid, if you post an answer about different env-variables for different users, I'll accept it as an answer since that was the problem I didn't think of...